# Cannot start mySQL "mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start')."

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I want to start mysql but this immediately shows up, I don't realy know how to solve it, can you please help me?

I have Ubuntu 14.04

this is what appears in the terminal.

```
dyphen@dyphen12-GNU:/etc/mysql$ sudo mysqld start
180510  5:55:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180510  5:55:25 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
180510  5:55:25 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 7158 ...
180510  5:55:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180510  5:55:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
180510  5:55:25 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180510  5:55:25 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
180510  5:55:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180510  5:55:27 InnoDB: 5.5.60 started; log sequence number 1595675
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
180510  5:55:27 [ERROR] Aborting

180510  5:55:27  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180510  5:55:28  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
180510  5:55:28 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: You'd pass `start` to an init script/tool, not mysqld itself. Something like `service mysql start`, since it's an older Ubuntu. Can't remember if 14 used systemd already.

Answer (score 4):

llja is right. I made the same mistake. To start mysqld, simply type

> mysqld

If a new problem surface, check /var/log/mysql/error.log for ERROR messages.